# How to adjust this view with constraints

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, storyboard

I'm totally new to Swift and in general, to iOS development. I just want to center a rounded profile picture with a table view above. In iPhone 5 it looks centered, but in iPhone 6 and 7 it look aligned to left, I don't know how to fix with constraints, I'm a little bit confuse.

**This is my constraint tree:**

[image: My constraint view]

**How it looks storyboard for iPhone5**

[image: How it looks in iPhone 5]

**How it looks storyboard for iPhone 6/7**

[image: How it looks in iPhone 6/7]

**This is how it looks in emulator with iPhone 6**

[image: In emulator]

Can you guys help me to figure out what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've set the width and height of your image view to hard-coded values, which will result in it looking centred for some views, but not all.

Reset your constraints, then set your distance from each of the four sides to zero. That'll centre your image!

Go to Editor -> Resolve Auto Layout Issues -> Reset to Suggested Constraints...

[image: Go to Editor -> Resolve Auto Layout Issues -> Reset to Suggested Constraints]

...then click that button down the bottom right and set each of your four sides' distances to zero.

[image]

Make sure you set Update Frames to "All Frames in Container" before clicking "Add 4 Constraints".

Answer (score 0):

Try setting horizontal constrain between your `My UI Image View` and `HeaderView`. You can set centre hozintal with `HeaderView`.
Go to button down the bottom right and set centre vertical and centre horizontal to your `My UI Image View`.

Hope it helps. Happy Coding!!